# Exclude files from project when publishing in Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net, file

I have some helpers.vb which I'm using in debug mode.

Now I would like to exclude them, when I publish a project.

Is there any config or something like that to handle this like in Visual Web Developer Express?

I found various threads where it's solved with a web.config file in Visual Web Developer Express

[How to exclude web.config when publishing with Visual Web Developer Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288858/how-to-exclude-web-config-when-publishing-with-visual-web-developer-express)

[Exclude files from web site publish in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650875/exclude-files-from-web-site-publish-in-visual-studio)

In Project Properties window/Publish there's an button called something like application files. Where I'm able to exclude the exe (which doesn't make sense for me) and the manifest. If you check the Show all files box, you will see a pbd and a xml, too. But I can't exclude vb files.

Comment: answered thoroughly here :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311390/segregating-debug-and-release-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: thanks for that, i use `#If DEBUG Then
        MsgBox("Mode Debug")
#Else
        MsgBox("Some other mode")
#End If` and it works great to call something only in debug mode. But isn't it possible to completly exclude a whole file from compiling? Or will I have to outsource the file as dll?