# Equivalent to Debug.Assert() for when the DEBUG symbol is not defined?

Tags: c#, assert

I am looking for syntax that will test an expression and throw an exception if the result is false AND the `DEBUG` symbol is missing. But not when it is there.

I know I can use:

```
#if !DEBUG
  Trace.Assert(condition);
#endif
```

And I know I can use:

```
#if !DEBUG
  SomeGlobal.Production = true;
#endif
```

So I can write:

```
Trace.Assert(SomeGlobal.Production && condition);
```

to avoid having the compilation instructions in different places.

Any other way?

Comment: how about `Debug.Assert(!condition)`

Comment: @YuliamChandra Read the question again, that’s the opposite of what OP wants.

Comment: What is the issue with the approach which you are using ie, `trace.assert(SomeGlobal.Production && condition);`

Comment: I tried to improve your title. You can change it back if it does not reflect what you meant.

Comment: Are you asking how you can detect `DEBUG` without using `#if`?

Comment: to the editor of the original post. when someone comes here saying "why the *** would you like to do that?" i'm blaming you:)

Comment: Why not, `static void CustomAssert(bool condition){ if(!condition) throw new Exception(); }`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segregating Debug and Release Code in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311390/segregating-debug-and-release-code-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230191/c-sharp-conditional-attribute for workarounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[Conditional("RELEASE")]
public static void AssertRelease(bool condition)
{
    Trace.Assert(condition);
}
```

And make sure to define "RELEASE" in Release configuration,

---

[ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good way to do this.

> Indicates to compilers that a method call or attribute should be ignored unless a specified conditional compilation symbol is defined.

Just like Debug.Assert, calls to this method are left out by the compiler if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
#if !DEBUG
#define NOTDEBUG
#endif

namespace Test123
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var someCondition = false;

            Trace(someCondition);
        }

        [Conditional("NOTDEBUG")]
        static void Trace(bool condition)
        {
            if (!condition)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288458(v=vs.71).aspx